# Auto calculate sum of data attribute in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, sum

I have tried for so long now to auto calculate the sum of data attribute when adding/removing something to a shopping basket from and calculate the total of data attribute in pure JavaScript no Jquery without being able to fix it! I am pretty new to JavaScript...

Here is my code:

HTML:
//The shopping basket section

```
<div id="basket">Shopping Basket</div>
    <ul class="cart" id="cart_id">
    </ul>

    <form>
        <br>Total Price:
        <input type="text" name="totalPrice" id="totalPrice" value="&euro; 0" disabled> 
    </form>
<div>
```

//The category selection section

```
 <ul class="products" id="product_id">
     <li class="cat" id="cat_id" name="data" data-title="iPad" data-price="299">iPad (&euro;299)<img class="plusicon" src="plusicon.jpg" alt="plusicon"/></li>
     <li class="cat" id="cat_id"  name="data" data-title="iPad Air" data-price="399">Ipad Air (&euro;399)<img class="plusicon" src="plusicon.jpg" alt="plusicon"/></li>
     <li class="cat" id="cat_id"  name="data" data-title="Sony Xperia Z2" data-price="399">Sony Xperia Z2 (&euro;399)<img class="plusicon" src="plusicon.jpg" alt="plusicon"/></li>
     <li class="cat" id="cat_id"  name="data" data-title="Samsung Galaxy Tab 10,1" data-price="349">Samsung Galaxy Tab 10,1 (&euro;349)<img class="plusicon" src="plusicon.jpg" alt="plusicon"/></li>

</ul>
```

**JS :**

```
function init(){
    plus = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".plusicon"), 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < plus.length; i++) {
        plus[i].addEventListener("click", addToBasasket, false);
    }
}

function addToBasket (e) {

    e.stopPropagation();

    var ele = info[plus.indexOf(this)];

    var title = ele.getAttribute("data-title");

    var price = parseInt(ele.getAttribute("data-price"));

    var ul = document.getElementById("cart_id");

    var li = document.createElement("li");  

    var remove = document.createElement("img");

    remove.className = "removeicon";
    remove.src = "removeicon.jpg";

    remove.addEventListener("click", removeThingFromList, false);
    li.appendChild(remove);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title+" (\u20AC"+price+")"));    
    ul.appendChild(li);

    //So when you press "plusicon" it adds to shopping basket and when you press "removeicon" it deletes from the basket!

    //Here below is my problem, I have tried for so long but I cant get to work
    //to show the total price when adding and removing li to basket!

    var total = 0;

    listItem = ele.getAttribute("data-price");

    for (var i=0; i < listItem.length; i++) 
    { 
        total += parseInt(ele.getAttribute("data-price")); 
    }

    document.querySelector("#totalPrice").value = total;
    //I have tried so many different ways but can't get it to work the total of attribute("data-price")!


    //This functions below works and removes the current li

    function removeThingFromList(e){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: But I am getting the current data-price fom var ele = info[plus.indexOf(this)];

Comment: Id should be unique, take a look at [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store the price in some attribute in new items (li) added to your basket :

```
li.appendChild(remove);
//Storing price in data-price attribute
li.setAttribute("data-price", price); 
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title+" (\u20AC"+price+")"));   
ul.appendChild(li);
```

And after that you can get this attribute and calculate the total :

```
var total = 0;
var listItem = document.getElementById("cart_id").getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i=0; i < listItem.length; i++) 
{ 
    total += parseInt(listItem[i].getAttribute("data-price")); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but this shows and calculates the total of the whole products data-price, not the certains that I am adding to the basket!?

Comment: You're welcome, please add an example of items inside basket, i want to know which class have the items inside `<ul class="cart" id="cart_id"></ul>` to change selector to this class.

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean? What should I add exactly?

Comment: When you add items in your basket you means that you add items inside `<ul class="cart" id="cart_id"></ul>` ?

Comment: When I press at plusicon it adds the current data-title and current data price to "cart_id" througt   
li.appendChild(remove);
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title+" (\u20AC"+price+")"));    
ul.appendChild(li);

Comment: Yes inside <ul class="cart" id="cart_id"></ul> through this var ul = document.getElementById("cart_id");

Comment: Ok i see, check my updated answer (updating fiddle also).

Comment: So please add an example of `<ul class="cart" id="cart_id"></ul>` with items `li`s  inside it instead of empty ul in your question, then i can know the exact item structure.

Comment: How do you mean sir? Should I add empty li's?

Comment: For exemple : How looks your basket if its have 2 items ? e.g <ul><li>....</li><li>...</li></ul> , post your real HTML.

Comment: Yes it keeps adding new <li> after every adding item.. <ul><li>...</li><li>..</li></ul> just like that...

Comment: Yes it works now! Thank you so much my friend!! I am only trying to remove and update the total sum now when I click on removeicon, that is the last my part!

Comment: I fixed that to, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li class="cart_item" data-prize="12.6" data-id="5">Hello €12.6</li>
  <li class="cart_item" data-prize="4.25" data-id="8">World €4.25</li>
  <li class="cart_item" data-prize="13.8" data-id="9">Foo €13.8</li>
  <li class="cart_item" data-prize="6.3" data-id="12">Bar €6.3</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="TOTAL" onclick="calculateTotal();">
<div id="messages"></div>

<script>
  function data(elm, key) {
    for(var i in elm.attributes) {
      if ( elm.attributes[i].name.substr(0, 5) === 'data-' ) {  // checks if the 5 first letters of the attribute are 'data-'
        // it's a data- attribute.  Now let's see if it's the right one
        if ( elm.attributes[i].name.substr(5) === key) {  // checks if the letters, next to the 5 first letters, correspond with the key we need
          return elm.attributes[i].value;
        }
      }
    }
    return '';
  }

  function calculateTotal() {
    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = '';
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("cart_item");
    var sum=0;
    for (var i in items) {
      var prize = Number( data(items[i], 'prize') );  // without the Number(), it's seen as text
      sum += prize;
      if(prize) {  // else it also shows blank lines
        document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += prize + '<br>';
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += '+ -----<br>' + sum;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it needs to be more like the way I posted the question.. Is there any easier solution than this? Also without innerHTML?

Comment: Personally I think you are not justified to think there is any advantage to using  document.createElement ... over innerHTML.  Do you know what a browser is really good at?  parsing a string of HTML. So any time you can generate a big chunk of HTML, setting that chunk as a innerHTML will be faster and more reliable than adding nodes with loops.  Do you have any specific requirement that is not met with my code?

Comment: It's just that I don't want to use innerHTML. If I use your code I will need to do several changes, I was just wondering if there is an easier way more closely to my code, specially that part which I have problem with, calculate the sum....